# test method for the following code

Tags: visualforce

```
/*
 * This class is the controller for the 
 * NewCustomer VisualForce page.
 * It uses properties to hold values entered 
 * by the user.  These values
 * will used to construct multiple SObjects.
 */  

public class Customer {

// Add properties here  

    public String companyName {get; set;}
public Integer numEmployees {get; set;}
public String streetAddress {get; set;}
public String cityAddress {get; set;}
public String stateAddress {get; set;}
public String postalCodeAddress {get; set;}
public String countryAddress {get; set;}
public String department {get; set;}
public String email {get; set;}
public String phone {get; set;}
public String firstName {get; set;}
public String lastName {get; set;}
public String title {get; set;}  

    /* Required method in a VisualForce controller */  

    public String getName() {
        return 'Customer';
    }
// Add methods here  

/*
  * Takes the values entered by the user in the VisualForce 
  * page and constructs Account and Contact sObjects.
  */
 public void save() {
     Account a = new Account(
         Name = companyName,
         NumberOfEmployees = numEmployees,
         ShippingStreet = streetAddress,
         ShippingCity = cityAddress,
         ShippingState = stateAddress,
         ShippingPostalCode = postalCodeAddress,
         ShippingCountry = countryAddress);

     insert a;

     Contact c = new Contact(
         FirstName = firstName,
         LastName = lastName,
         Account = a,
         Department = department,
         Email = email,
         Phone = phone,
         Title = title,
         MailingStreet = streetAddress,
         MailingCity = cityAddress,
         MailingState = stateAddress,
         MailingPostalCode = postalCodeAddress,
         MailingCountry = countryAddress);

     insert c;
 }

// Add queries here  

/* Used for the Account list at the end of the 
    VisualForce page 
 */
 public List<Account> getAccountList() {
     return [select name, numberofemployees from account];
 }

 /* Used for the Contact list at the end of the 
    VisualForce page 
 */
 public List<Contact> getContactList() {
     return [select name, title, department, email, phone 
             from contact];
 }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, badri. You forgot to include your test method and the problems you are encountering; otherwise it looks like you are asking us to completely write your test method, which is not an acceptable question for this site.

Comment: Hi @badri! Welcome to SFSE. As Mike said, this isn't clear what you are trying to do. If you are simply looking for someone to write all of the code for you, it won't happen on this site. Please check out some community tips and tricks for asking a good question - http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273/tips-and-tricks-for-asking-a-good-question

Answer (score 1):

Do not expect full code here without showing some efforts you did. But if you want to learn how test classes are written in salesforce visit this link http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

and

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests